Translation of organic compound in classical Chinese
I have a question of "organic compound 有機化合物". Here I quote the first sentence from https://zh-classical.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%89%E6%A9%9F%E5%8C%96%E5%90%88%E7%89%A9.

有機化合物，略作有機物，一譯官品，碳化合物也，為生命之本

Why 有機化合物 is called 官品?

there’s a wiki page 華製新漢語及中文固有語 mentioned:

【官品】有機物、有機體、（官，即organ；品，謂一類事物。）

that, 嚴復 invented this term 
organ —> 器官
“品”, the same usage as “某一類東西的總稱”, like “必需品”, “補品”
have fun :)

Thanks for the reference!

官品 is not a good translation because organic compounds have nothing to do with 器官. If anything, 碳品 would be a better translation.
